# Equivalent for value-property for controls in winforms

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, winforms

I'm used to webdeveloping, and when I work with databases, I usually use some text for the `Text`-property of a radio button, and the row's ID as `Value`-property. This makes it very easy to save to databases.

Is the an equivalent in winforms for the `Value`-property, or will I have to identify rows based on the text in the control?

Comment: Can you give a more elaborate example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to save data from radiobutton selection to a database. The radiobuttons are already populated from another table in the database, so it would be proper to insert the radiobutton-selection into the database based on ID's, rather than the text of the radiobutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general state storage mechanism, there is a [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) property on all controls. You can put whatever you like in there.

Comment: So, is it usual to use the `Tag` property in examples like mine? I mean, to store the database row ID in the `Tag` and some title in the row, as `Text` property?

Comment: That depends... Most controls do have their own properties specific to their functionality for this. For example, ComboBox has SelectedValue that you can use once binding items correctly.

Comment: Well, I tried using the `Tag` for this purpose, and it worked fine. I'm not sure if it's the right "thing" to do, but it works.